# PHP Adwords API get Upgraded URLs

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm trying to retrieve the Upgraded URLs via the Adwords API, but all I'm gettings is NULL. I'm using the latest version of the client library (v201502)
Here's the code I'm using

```
    $adGroupAdService = $this->oGAW->GetService('AdGroupAdService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('AdGroupId');

    // Create predicates.
    $selector->predicates[] =
        new Predicate('AdGroupId', 'IN', array($adGroupId));
    $selector->predicates[] =
        new Predicate('AdType', 'IN', array('TEXT_AD', 'DYNAMIC_SEARCH_AD'));

    // Create paging controls.
    $selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);

    $page = $adGroupAdService->get($selector);
```

And it returns this

```
object(TextAd)[107]
  public 'headline' => string 'headline'
  public 'description1' => string 'description1' 
  public 'description2' => string 'description2'
  public 'id' => string '76813511440' (length=11)
  public 'url' => null
  public 'displayUrl' => string 'test.nl/test'
  public 'finalUrls' => null
  public 'finalMobileUrls' => null
  public 'finalAppUrls' => null
  public 'trackingUrlTemplate' => null
  public 'urlCustomParameters' => null
  public 'devicePreference' => null
  public 'AdType' => string 'TextAd' (length=6)
  private '_parameterMap' (Ad) => 
    array (size=1)
      'Ad.Type' => string 'AdType' (length=6)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a silly question, but is the ad you are pulling down using the upgraded URL's or is it using the destinationUrl still?

Comment: It's using the final url, but it returns null on all ads using final urls. ads using destination urls are working fine.

There's an example in the client library on how to add a final url, but I can't find anything on how to pull them back down.

Comment: One other thing to check is that the final url is going to return as a an array of strings rather than just a string. Is your code setup to handle this? https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/AdGroupAdService.TextAd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a work around, I'm now using the ReportDefinitionService to get the AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT for today.

Final Urls are shown in the csv it returns.

```
$oAdwords = Utility_Adwords::getInstance($iCredentials);
$user = $oAdwords->getAdwordsUser($iCredentials, $iCustomerId);
// Load the service, so that the required classes are available.
$user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService', ADWORDS_VERSION_SPEND);

// Create selector.
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('CampaignId', 'CampaignName','CampaignStatus', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'AdGroupName', 'AdGroupStatus',  'Status', 'AdType', 'DisplayUrl', 'CreativeDestinationUrl', 'CreativeFinalUrls', 'CreativeTrackingUrlTemplate', 'CreativeUrlCustomParameters');

// Filter out removed criteria.
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', 'IN', $aCampaigns);
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('AdGroupStatus', 'NOT_IN', array('REMOVED'));
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Status', 'NOT_IN', array('DISABLED'));

// Create report definition.
$reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
$reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
$reportDefinition->reportName = 'Ad Performance Report #' . uniqid();
$reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'TODAY';
$reportDefinition->reportType = 'AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
$reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';

// Set additional options.
$options = array('version' => ADWORDS_VERSION_SPEND);

ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);
```

Answer (score 2):

The field you're looking for is 'CreativeFinalUrls', just add this to your selector fields and it'll return an array of final urls in textAd.finalUrls.

```
$selector->fields = array('AdGroupId', 'CreativeFinalUrls');
```

see https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields?hl=en#v201506